# working on multiple branches within svn

Tags: svn

i am new to svn and am trying to grasp a fundamental concept: i would like to switch from one branch (branch1) to another branch (branch2), without having to setup a server for each path.

my server's root:  /root/
my app is located in folder 'app' and all files are located via relative addressing:  i.e.  app/css/main.css

the way our svn system seems to be configured is that i create a working copy locally into /root/ within a folder named 'app'.

this is great for one branch, but if i need a second branch it asks me where to put it, and my options seem to be to put it into the same folder which would overwrite my existing branch, or create a new folder, which will break all the links relying on the app/ path.

branch1's root: /app/
branch2's root: /app2/  ???

i apologize for the lack of clarity of my question; the only comparison i know to make is with switching branches in git. if i switch branch from branch1 to branch2 using git, then refresh my browser, branch2 is now being displayed. i am not a git guru, but i suspect my git-way-of-thinking may be inhibiting me from seeing the solution.

thanks for your help and patience!
bill

Comment: it would help me write better questions in the future if the people downvoting this question explained their reasons. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to read a bit on svn : http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.initial.html . In essence you can switch between branches from within same working directory in svn same way as with git. Unless the svn repository layout is badly designed: in svn branches and tags are just a subdirectories of the repo, whereas trunk is rougly equivalent to git's master.